# Using a Storybook arg to set a nested arg

Tags: javascript, reactjs, storybook

So I have a story in storybook like so:

```
export const One = Template.bind();
One.args = {
  children: [
    <MyComponent {...Icon.args} headerText={"Header"} />,
    <MyComponent {...Standard.args}  />
  ]
};
```

Say the `Standard.args` I'm getting look like this:

```
Standard.args = {
  headerText: "Default Header",
  detailText: "Default details"
};
```

I'd like to be able to set the `detailText` value using a distinct arg, but don't know of a way to do it. Something like the below, but obviously with working syntax:

```
export const One = Template.bind();
One.args = {
  detailText: "new detail text",
  children: [
    <MyComponent {...Icon.args} headerText={"Header"} />,
    <MyComponent {...Standard.args} detailText={detailText} />
  ]
};
```

Is this possible?

Comment: have you solved this?

Comment: No, I think I ended up having to do more of a composed story with all the props at the same level

Answer (score 0):

I use this workaround that is working for me. First I define the nested content:

```
const ContentOne = () => (<div>This is content one.</div>);

const ContentTwo = () => (<div>This is content two.</div>);
```

Then I create templates for each content:

```
const TemplateOne = (args) => (
  <YourComponent {...args}>
    <ContentOne />    
  </YourComponent>
)

const TemplateTwo = (args) => (
  <YourComponent {...args}>
    <ContentTwo />    
  </YourComponent>
)
```

And finally I export the components:

```
export const ComponentOne = TemplateOne.bind({});
ComponentOne.args = {
  detailText: "One detail text",
};

export const ComponentTwo = TemplateTwo.bind({});
ComponentTwo.args = {
  detailText: "Two detail text",
};
```